# How can I tell my Linux installation to handle the brightness ketys with ACPID?

Tags: linux, brightness, acpi, backlight, events

I want to manually control my brightness keys making a event on `/etc/acpi/events`.

Only that there is a problem, when I press the brightness up/down keys, the brighness changes (I think that the BIOS is changing it) before my script is called. I tried to change `LINUX_CMDLINE` but I don't know how to tell the system to handle the brightness.